# Hibernate found hibernate.cfg.xml but method no

Tags: java, xml, database, spring, hibernate

yeah i know what you think that i didn't try resolve, check other topics etc. I read other topics but anywhere I can't find same problem as my.

Console give me this stacktrace:

```
20-Dec-2016 20:59:19.482 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-7]      
org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure HHH000042: Configuring from file: 
hibernate.cfg.xml
Enitial SessionFactory creation failedorg.hibernate.HibernateException:    
could not find file: spring-mvc-angularjs-          
master\src\main\java\com\user\springmvcangularjs\hibernate.cfg.xml
```

Well in first line i got information about that springe configuring from file hibernate.cfg.xml, but when i try connect with database i have error "could not find file".

I try all solutions but any helped me.

My code:
HibernateUtill class

```
public class HibernateUtil {

    private static final SessionFactory ourSessionFactory;
    private static final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

    static {
        try {

            Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.configure();

            serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configuration.getProperties()).build();
            ourSessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Enitial SessionFactory creation failed" + ex);

            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }



    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {

        return ourSessionFactory;

    }

 }
```

Method in UserService class:

```
@Override
public void save(User user)
{

    HibernateUtil hibernateUtil = new HibernateUtil();
    SessionFactory sessFact = hibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = sessFact.getCurrentSession();
    org.hibernate.Transaction tr = session.beginTransaction();





    System.out.println(tr.isActive());

    session.save(user);

    tr.commit();
    sessFact.close();

}
```

PS I have hibernate.cfg.xml file in spring-mvc-angularjs-master/src/main/java

Comment: Have you tried spring-mvc-angularjs-master/src/main/resources?  That would be the standard place for a maven project.

Comment: I dont have resources directory, but i tried on webapp and this same error.

Comment: Create a resources directory and put it in there.  The resources directory in a maven project ends up at WEB-INF/classes which is where you want this file.

Comment: @stdunbar Thanks for your answer. I tried this what you said, but this same. Here is screen with my code (path) and directories https://i.gyazo.com/b13fde698d9cfb5515531fe1b424b484.png. I'm not sure that all is okey. If you can check please ;)

Comment: Take a look at a tutorial - https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/hibernate/hibernate-tutorial-beginners-examples/ - you need to put the file just in "resources" - not in "resources/WEB-INF" and then you don't need to tell hibernate where to find it - it is in the default place.  Let us know how that works.

Comment: @stdunbar Thanks Sir! All is working!